# Returning ONLY the max EventDate from a history table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with information about vehicles and events that happen on these vehicles. EX:

`VehicleEvent`

```
VehicleRefNum | EventTypeCode    | EventDate
      1       | OutOfService     | 2017-06-28
      2       | EngineRepair     | 2016-05-15                         
      3       | OutOfService     | 2016-04-02                         
      4       | OtherRepair      | 2017-07-21                        
      1       | ReturnToService  | 2017-07-01                             
      5       | NewToService     | 2017-07-27 
      6       | OutOfService     | 2017-05-15                            
      3       | ReturnToService  | 2016-04-21 
      1       | OutOfService     | 2017-07-09                                      
      1       | ReturnToService  | 2017-07-11
```

I am looking to return a list of each vehicles most recent ReturnToService if the vehicle has one, otherwise I want to ignore it.

Ex Results:

```
VehicleRefNum | EventTypeCode    | EventDate                      
      3       | ReturnToService  | 2016-04-21                              
      1       | ReturnToService  | 2017-07-11
```

It looks like I need is a subquery as a WHERE clause but what I really need is some help. Thanks!

Edited to add:

```
Select VehicleRefNum, EventTypeCode, EventDate
From VehicleEvent
where VehicleRefNum = 1
and EventDate = Select max(EventDate) from VehicleEvent)
```

will work but only gives me half of the solution I am looking for. I need a query that will scale with more vehicles and events.

Comment: Hint: `WHERE` and `Group BY`

Comment: I'm not sure of the performance difference, but when scaling for massive amounts of data, you can also try a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleRefNum, EventTypeCode ORDER BY EventDate DESC) AS rn ..... WHERE rn = 1`.

Comment: @Collatrl I noticed you un-accepted my answer (saw I lost rep).. Did you have an issue with it?

Comment: Hey! I must have typed my comment and not submitted it. So I ran your query as-is and I get the full set of records for Vehicle 1. It returns 4 rows (1 for each event).

If I run

    SELECT VehicleRefNum, MAX(EventDate) 
    EventDate
    FROM VehicleEvent
    WHERE EventTypeCode = 'ReturnToService'
    GROUP BY VehicleRefNum

I get the the VehicleRefNum and the MAX EventDate (so only 1 record) but missing the EventTypeCode

Comment: and if I run 

SELECT VehicleRefNum, EventTypeCode, MAX(EventDate) EventDate FROM VehicleEvent WHERE EventTypeCode = 'ReturnToService' GROUP BY VehicleRefNum

`EventTypeCode is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

@aaron-dietz -- see my last 2 comments

Comment: @Collatrl Hey, I'm confused.. I double-checked it here in case I was missing something, but that query works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1fb2/1/0

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT VehicleRefNum, EventTypeCode, MAX(EventDate) EventDate
FROM VehicleEvent
WHERE EventTypeCode = 'ReturnToService'
GROUP BY VehicleRefNum, EventTypeCode
```

The `WHERE` will limit the results to the `EventTypeCode` you're interested in.  Then from there, you want to roll the results up on the common `VehicleRefNum / EventTypeCode` combinations, which you do with `GROUP BY`, and see only the `MAX(EventDate)` for each.